# In Vue3 + element-plus, how to pass a component with arguments to another component as a prop

Tags: vuejs3, element-plus

Vue beginner here.

I have a simple custom component:

MaterialIcon.vue:

```
<script lang="ts">
export default {
  props: ['iconname']
}
</script>

<template>
  <span class="material-icons-outlined md-18">{{iconname}}</span>
</template>
```

And, as per element-plus docs (https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/button.html#button-attributes), I want to pass it as a component to be used as an icon in a button. How to get this done, specially considering my custom component has an argument?

```
<el-button type="primary" title="Refresh" :icon="???"/>
```

the below works, but the problem with that solution is that the loading feature (which replaces the icon with a spinner) appears on the side of my custom icon, if I do that (instead of replacing the icon, as it should). Also, it would be pointless to have a component with that approach - with that approach, I could just use the one-liner syntax in my component definition instead.

```
<el-button type="primary" title="Refresh">
  <material-icon icon_name="refresh"/>
</el-button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html) if you want to put something inside a component.

The Element+ [Button](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/button.html) component has 3 [Slots](https://element-plus.org/en-US/#button-slots)

- default  - customize default content
- loading  - customize loading component
- icon     - customize icon component

So, if you want to replace the icon, then use the `icon` slot.

```
<template #icon>
   <material-icon iconname="refresh"/>
</template>
```

Check the [Docs](https://element-plus.org/en-US/#button-slots) about the slots.

Pay attention to your `icon_name` attribute. It should not have the underline symbol, if your Prop does not have it.

For Naming/Using Props check the [Prop Passing Details](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-passing-details)